# Remove duplicates based on two columns and reversed values

Tags: sql, duplicates

Let's say we have following table:

```
Select 
    'a' as col1,
    'b' as col2
union
Select 
    'a' as col1,
    'c' as col2
union
Select 
    'b' as col1,
    'a' as col2
```

It gives:

```
col1 col2
"a" "b"
"a" "c"
"b" "a"
```

How would you define duplicated row assuming that rows like ("a", "b") and ("b", "a") are the same.

So in fact result should be:

```
col1 col2
"a" "b"
"a" "c"
```

Comment: Is there any column that can represent the order? and What's your dbms? thanks

Answer (score 1):

judging by your sample data and results you could use a query like below

```
select 
distinct
case when t2.col1 is not null and t2.col1<t1.col1 then t2.col1 else t1.col1 end as col1,
case when t2.col2 is not null and t2.col2>t1.col2 then t2.col2 else t1.col2 end as col2
from yourtable t1 
left join yourtable t2
on t1.col1=t2.col2 and t1.col2=t2.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Databricks, I can do something as follows and it works.  It seems you need to have id to select distinct records by ignoring field order.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a AS
SELECT uuid() as id, col1, col2 FROM your_table;

SELECT a1.col1, a2.col2
FROM table_a a1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table_a a2
                  WHERE a1.col1 = a2.col2 
                        AND a1.col2 = a2.col1
                        AND a1.id > a2.id);
```